# maximum websocket connections in browsers

Tags: javascript, browser, websocket

I want to do some stress test against my websocket server runnig this javascript example in my browser (chrome) below:

```
  function create_ws() {
    var ws=new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1/");
    ws.onopen=function(evt){
      var binary = new Uint8Array(2);
      binary[0]=1;
      binary[1]=2;
      ws.send(binary.buffer);                  
    };
    ws.onclose=function(evt){};
    ws.onmessage=function(evt){};
    ws.onerror=function(evt){};
  }

 var connections = [];
 var numberOfconnections=100;

 for(var i = 0; i < numberOfconnections; i++) {
  connections.push(create_ws());
 }
```

The problem is the script above let me run only about 100 connections at the same time.  If i increase  `numberOfconnections` to 300 it throws following error:
 `WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES`

Is there a way to increase the number of websocket connections in browser?

Answer (score 2):

Try to open new tabs with your stress test manually or with `window.open` in code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the limit for chromium is set to 256 per the discussion below:

[Chromium Discussion](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=429419#c2)

It's possible other browsers have different limits.  As I only use so many connections for stress testing, I plan to open a few windows to go outside the limit.